# How to optimize the code?Sum square difference code?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

**Sum Square Difference Problem**

**Input Format**

First-line contains that denotes the number of test cases. This is followed by lines **T**, each containing an integer, **N**.

**Constraints**

*1<=T<=10000*

*1<=N<=10000*

**Sample Input**

> 2
>
> 3
>
> 10

**Sample Output**

> 22
>
> 2640

```
t = int(input().strip())
for a0 in range(t):
    count=sum_of=0
    n = int(input().strip())
    for i in range(n+1):
        count+=i
        sum_of+=pow(i,2)
    print(pow(count,2)-sum_of)
```

**Explanation**

[Explanation of sum square difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d44u.jpg)

**Problem:**

If the **N** is greater than 10, It was shown Timeout Error. How to optimize.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/ (basically, use a closed formula, you don't need a loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Sum of first `n` natural numbers is `n * (n + 1) / 2`.
- Squared sum of first `n` natural numbers is `n * (n + 1) * (2n + 1) / 6`. For mathematical induction, you can refer [`this`](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/) as mentioned by amit in the comments.

So your code would look like below giving an `O(1)` complexity:

```
t = int(input().strip())
for a0 in range(t):
    n = int(input().strip())
    n_sum = n * (n + 1) // 2
    sum_square = n_sum * n_sum
    squared_sum = n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) // 6
    print(sum_square - squared_sum)
```